# Create a dimmed background on-click

Tags: javascript, html, css

Hopefully not too vague. All I want to do is make the entire page go dim after clicking a link. I would imagine having `div style="height:100%; width=100%;"` with a high `z-index`. to cover the webpage. My question is toggling this div. I'm not sure what I should even use to accomplish this.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Demos [using jQuery](http://jsfiddle.net/3vGqp/1/)** or **[using bog-standard Javascript](http://jsfiddle.net/3vGqp/2/)**, both showing how you can toggle the element.

**HTML** You didn't say how you want to toggle this. Using a button?

```
<button onclick="dim();">Dim</button>
<div id="dimmer"></div>
```

but bear in mind the dimmer will go over the button

**CSS**

```
#dimmer
{
    background:#000;
    opacity:0.5;
    position:fixed; /* important to use fixed, not absolute */
    top:0;
    left:0;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    display:none;
    z-index:9999; /* may not be necessary */
}
```

N.B. Use `position: fixed` as 100% height is only the window height and if your document is larger, using `position: absolute` doesn't dim the whole document - you can scroll to see there are contents visible.

**Javascript**

```
function dim(bool)
{
    if (typeof bool=='undefined') bool=true; // so you can shorten dim(true) to dim()
    document.getElementById('dimmer').style.display=(bool?'block':'none');
}    

dim(true); // on
dim(false); // off
```

Comment: This is perfect actually. Thanks (Y)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with a simple JavaScript

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/vSnWB/)

HTML

```
<a href="#" onclick="dim_div()">Click me</a>
<div id="toggle_div"></div>
Hello World
```

JavaScript

```
function dim_div() {
    document.getElementById("toggle_div").style.display="block";
}
```

CSS

```
#toggle_div {
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .6);
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 999;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

HTML

```
<div id="initial_opacity_zero"></div>
<button id="button_to_adjust_opacity" onclick="func_onclick();"></button>
```

CSS

```
div#initial_opacity_zero{
  opacity:0;
  display:block;
  position:fixed;
  top:0px; right:0px; bottom:0px; left:0px;
}
```

JavaScript:

```
function func_onclick(){
  document.getElementById("initial_opacity_zero").style.opacity="0.6";
}
```