# Dim webpage around a video

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to dim the webpage around the video, although I tried to dim by button, that didn't work for me [This example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14013924/create-a-dimmed-background-on-click), what I want is for the site to automatically dim as I enter the site, 
[image]

(the image)

My site automatically plays a video upon entry and I want the whitespace to be dimmed, similar to what youtube magic options does. My css looks like such,

```
#encase {
    width: 1280px;
    height: 820px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    font-size: 1em;
}
#blankSpace {
    width: 1280px;
    height: 100px;
    border: 1px solid yellow;
}
#wholeBody {
    width: 1280px;
    height: 720px;
    border: 1px solid green;
}
#body {
    width: 1280px;
    height: 720px;
}
```

It is 1 massive container that has 3 divs in it, blankspace just to center the video with another div containing the body. Or if it's impossible, how to dim on button click (as the other method doesn't work for me). Thank You. [JsFiddle click dim (doesn't work)](https://jsfiddle.net/wayrguxr/1/)

Comment: Can you share some HTML? Preferably a working JSFiddle or Codepen

Comment: You just need a backdrop for you video and give that a semi-transparent background.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/wayrguxr/1/

Comment: From the CSS you have in your question, how do you plan on dimming the page if you don't set a background color? It is white by default.

Comment: Hey Timo, say for my encase, if I set a background colour, won't that only dim the size of the div? Not the whitespace around it?

Comment: Yes, so you would need a div that covers the whole page i.e. 100% width and height and position the video inside that div

Comment: @Timo, I tried your method and it worked, but, the video also had the grey background on it aswell.

Comment: @Mad_Questionnaire: Use the overlay with `z-index`. Make the `z-index` of the `div` you want to focus as higher than the overlay. Once you get it right, then trigger the `css` change on page load via javascript. For example: http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/np98x9a8/ (*using an image instead of video for demo*)

Comment: @Abhitalks I tried your method, http://i.stack.imgur.com/gT6vn.jpg and this is the code https://jsfiddle.net/np98x9a8/1/ .But it still overlays the video even though I made the body div 999 whilst the encase is 999.

Comment: @Mad_Questionnaire: I don't see any overlay in your code. Why are you fiddling with `encase`. Your video is inside `div#body` and that is what you need to change the `z-index` for.

Comment: @Abhitalks My overlay is encase, which is 100% width and height, I also added a z index to div#body. I removed the z-index from the encase div but the grey is still overlapping with the video.

Comment: @Mad_Questionnaire: Your `encase` cannot be an overlay. Because, it contains the rest of the contents of your page as well along with the video itself. You need to use a different `div` for overlay which needs to be `absolute`ly positioned. Please study the code in my earlier fiddle carefully. Also, see this: https://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/np98x9a8/4/

Comment: Quite interesting how you have to position the body relative and the overlay absolute for it to work. I got it now, thank you @Abhitalks and everyone else.